# SQL Cursor problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following errors but can't figure out why..

> Msg 16915, Level 16, State 1, Procedure client_myClientsProc, Line
>   46
>   A cursor with the name 'cur_keywords' already exists.
>   Msg 16905, Level 16, State 1, Procedure client_myClientsProc, Line
>   47
>   The cursor is already open.

And then if I try to run it again it says

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure client_myClientsProc Line 49
>   Invalid object name '##CLIENTS_KEYWORD.

Now this is old code that I am trying to fix, so please bear with me...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[client_myclientsproc]  
   @Keywords varchar(max),  
   @Delimiter varchar(10) = ' '  
AS  
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  

  DECLARE @MYQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX);    
  DECLARE @tempkeyword varchar(4000)    
  DECLARE @TempCount INT   

  IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..##CLIENTS_KEYWORD') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
     DROP TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int)  
  END

  IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD(productid int)
  END  

  SET @MYQUERY = 'SELECT clientID, Client_Name FROM MYCLIENTS WHERE  ClientID IN ';                    

 IF(@Delimiter<>'none')
 BEGIN   
  DECLARE cur_keywords CURSOR FOR  
    select value from SC_Split(@Keywords,@Delimiter)     

  OPEN cur_keywords  

  FETCH NEXT FROM cur_keywords into @tempkeyword  
  INSERT ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id) exec getClientsByKeyword @tempkeyword  

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0     

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_keywords into @tempkeyword  

     INSERT ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id) exec getClientsByKeyword @tempkeyword 
          select @TempCount=COUNT(client_id) from  ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD     
            IF(@TempCount<>0)    
                BEGIN    
                    DELETE FROM ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD WHERE client_id NOT IN(SELECT client_id from ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD)     
       INSERT  ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD (client_id) (select client_id from ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD)                       
                END  
       CLOSE cur_keywords                              
       DEALLOCATE cur_keywords                                  
 END
 ELSE 
 BEGIN  
   print(@Keywords)
   INSERT ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id) exec getClientsByKeyword @Keywords      
 END  

 SET @MYQUERY = @MYQUERY + '(SELECT * FROM ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD)'                           
 SET @MYQUERY = @MYQUERY + ' ORDER BY NAME'                    

 print    @MYQUERY   

 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @MYQUERY                                           
END  
GO
```

====================

get clients by keyword code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getClientsByKeyword]  
 @Keyword varchar(max)  

AS  
BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON;  


 select                     
  DISTINCT(clients.clientID)
 from                     
  Clients_Table clients                               
  left join clientNumber cn on cn.clientid=clients.clientid                    
 where                     
  clients.activeind = 1                     
  and (clients.Name like '%' + @Keyword + '%'                     
  or clients.clientNum LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'           
  or cn.clientN like   '%' + @Keyword + '%' )      

END  



GO
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: What does `getClientsByKeyword` do? Would it be straightforward to replace that with a simple join or (if more complex) put the logic into a table valued function then you can drop the cursor entirely.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your cursor code is doing but can't you just join directly from the split function to the Clients table?

Comment: it seems it just splits the string 'Keyword' so if for instance you have  'dell panasonic mitsubishi' it will return the list of clientids in a column 101,102,103 etcc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your `OPEN`, `FETCH`, `WHILE`, `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` are misplaced.
- Your temp tables need creating every time.

Try this refactored script. Modify as you need:

```
DECLARE @tempkeyword varchar(4000)    
DECLARE @TempCount INT   

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..##CLIENTS_KEYWORD') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD

CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int)  

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD

CREATE TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD(productid int)

SET @MYQUERY = 'SELECT clientID, Client_Name FROM MYCLIENTS WHERE  ClientID IN ';                    

IF(@Delimiter<>'none')
BEGIN       
     DECLARE cur_keywords CURSOR FOR  
        SELECT value FROM SC_Split(@Keywords,@Delimiter)     

      OPEN cur_keywords  
      FETCH NEXT FROM cur_keywords into @tempkeyword  
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0     
      BEGIN
         FETCH NEXT FROM cur_keywords into @tempkeyword  

         INSERT ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id) exec getClientsByKeyword @tempkeyword               
         INSERT ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id) exec getClientsByKeyword @tempkeyword 
         SELECT @TempCount=COUNT(client_id) from  ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD     
         IF(@TempCount<>0)    
         BEGIN    
              DELETE FROM ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD 
                  WHERE client_id NOT IN(SELECT client_id from ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD);

                  INSERT  ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD (client_id) 
                  SELECT  client_id from ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD;
         END  
      END

     CLOSE cur_keywords                              
     DEALLOCATE cur_keywords                                  
END
ELSE 
BEGIN  
   print(@Keywords)
   INSERT ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id) exec getClientsByKeyword @Keywords      
END  

SELECT @MYQUERY=@MYQUERY + '(SELECT * FROM ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD) ORDER BY NAME'                           
print    @MYQUERY   
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @MYQUERY                                           
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Did the stored procedure error out previously? It looks like the `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` statements were not run, which could happen if the code hit an error since there is no `TRY..CATCH` in your code or other method to make sure that the cursor has been properly cleared out. Try disconnecting (or manually running the `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` in the same connection) and running it again.

The second error is probably for similar reasons - poor clean-up. When you enter the stored procedure the code `DROP`s the temporary table if it already exists. The `CREATE` is in the `ELSE` portion of that statement though. That means that if the table already exists then it will be `DROP`ped and never recreated.

Answer (score 1):

Without setting up test tables this end I'm not really sure what your code is doing but I think you can probably avoid use of a cursor at all with something based on the below.

```
;WITH C
     AS (select clients.clientID,
                clients.Name,
                clients.clientNum,
                cn.clientN
         from   Clients_Table clients
                left join clientNumber cn
                  on cn.clientid = clients.clientid
                     AND clients.activeind = 1)
select value,
       clients.clientID
from   SC_Split(@Keywords, @Delimiter)
       JOIN C
         ON ( C.Name like '%' + value + '%'
               or C.clientNum LIKE '%' + value + '%'
               or C.clientN like '%' + value + '%' )
```